# Why are XOR often used in java hashCode() but another bitwise operators are used rarely?

Tags: hash, hashcode, xor

I often see code like

```
int hashCode(){
  return a^b;
}
```

Why XOR?

Comment: Possible Duplicate --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379952/why-is-xor-used-on-cryptography

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Of all bit-operations XOR has the best bit shuffling properties.

This truth-table explains why:

```
A B AND
0 0  0
0 1  0
1 0  0
1 1  1

A B OR
0 0  0
0 1  1
1 0  1
1 1  1

A B XOR
0 0  0
0 1  1
1 0  1
1 1  0
```

As you can see for AND and OR do a poor job at mixing bits.

OR will on average produce 3/4 one-bits. AND on the other hand will produce on average 3/4 null-bits. Only XOR has an even one-bit vs. null-bit distribution. That makes it so valuable for hash-code generation.

Remember that for a hash-code you want to use as much information of the key as possible and get a good distribution of hash-values. If you use AND or OR you'll get numbers that are biased towards either numbers with lots of zeros or numbers with lots of ones.

Answer (score 24):

XOR has the following advantages:

- It does not depend on order of computation i.e. a^b = b^a
- It does not "waste" bits. If you change even one bit in one of the components, the final value will change.
- It is quick, a single cycle on even the most primitive computer.
- It preserves uniform distribution. If the two pieces you combine are uniformly distributed so will the combination be. In other words, it does not tend to collapse the range of the digest into a narrower band.

More info [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/hashcode.html).

Comment: An xor operation doesn't waste bits *if* all the input bits are independent, but if it merges bits which are strongly correlated it may waste a lot.  For example, if one has a type that represents a pair of numbers in the range 0-65535 and forms a hash by xor'ing the numbers together, the upper 16 bits which are zero in every value will be zero in the hash code.  Worse, if a disproportionate number of instances (e.g. 10%) have both numbers match, that same proportion of instances will return zero for the hash.

Answer (score 5):

XOR operator is reversible, i.e. suppose I have a bit string as `0  0  1` and I XOR it with another bit string `1  1  1`, the the output is

```
0 xor 1 = 1
0     1 = 1
1     1 = 0
```

Now I can again xor the 1st string with the result to get the 2nd string. i.e.

```
0   1 = 1
0   1 = 1
1   0 = 1
```

So, that makes the 2nd string a key. This behavior is not found with other bit operator

Please see this for more info --> [Why is XOR used on Cryptography?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379952/why-is-xor-used-on-cryptography)

Comment: hashCode don't need to be inverted.
//Sorry for my bad English

Comment: yes, but one use of XOR in cryptography is its reversibility nature.

Answer (score 1):

There is another use case: objects **in which (some) fields must be compared without regarding their order**. For example, if you want a pair `(a, b)` be always equal to the pair `(b, a)`.
XOR has the property that `a ^ b` = `b ^ a`, so it can be used in hash function in such cases.

Examples: (full code [here](http://ideone.com/znGOJR))

definition:

```
final class Connection {
    public final int A;
    public final int B;

    // some code omitted

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Connection that = (Connection) o;

        return (A == that.A && B == that.B || A == that.B && B == that.A);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return A ^ B;
    }

    // some code omitted
}
```

usage:

```
        HashSet<Connection> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add(new Connection(1, 3));
        s.add(new Connection(2, 3));
        s.add(new Connection(3, 2));
        s.add(new Connection(1, 3));
        s.add(new Connection(2, 1));

        s.remove(new Connection(1, 2));

        for (Connection x : s) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }

        // output:
        // Connection{A=2, B=3}
        // Connection{A=1, B=3}
```