# Hashcode generated by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hashcode

In SO I have read several answers related to the implementation of hashcode and the suggestion to use the XOR operator. (E.g. [Why are XOR often used in java hashCode() but another bitwise operators are used rarely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334218/why-are-xor-often-used-in-java-hashcode-but-another-bitwise-operators-are-used)).

When I use Eclipse to generate the hashcode function where `field` is an object and `timestamp` a long, the output is:

```
public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result
        + field == null) ? 0 : field.hashCode());
  return result;
}
```

Is there any reason by not using the XOR operator like below?

```
  result = prime * result + (int) (timestamp ^ (timestamp >>> 32));
```

Comment: I see an XOR here `prime * result + (int) (timestamp ^ (timestamp >>> 32))`...

Comment: @Heuster thats his EDIT miss. Actually Eclipse creates only this line `result = prime * result + field == null) ? 0 : field.hashCode());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse takes the safe way out. Although the calculation method that uses a prime, a multiplication, and an addition is slower than a single XOR, it gives you an overall better hash code in situations when you have multiple fields.

Consider a simple example - a class with two `String`s, `a` and `b`. You can use

```
a.hashCode() ^ b.hashCode()
```

or

```
a.hashCode() * 31 + b.hashCode()
```

Now consider two objects:

```
a = "ABC"; b = "XYZ"
```

and

```
a = "XYZ"; b = "ABC"
```

The first method will produce identical hash codes for them, because XOR is symmetric; the second method will produce different hash codes, which is good, because the objects are not equal. In general, you want non-equal objects to have different hash codes as often as possible, to improve performance of hash-based containers of these objects. The `31*a+b` method achieves this goal better than XOR.

Note that when you are dealing with portions of the same object, as in

```
timestamp ^ (timestamp >>> 32)
```

the above argument is much weaker: encountering two timestamps such that the only difference between them is that their upper and lower parts are swapped is harder to imagine than two objects with swapped `a` and `b` field values.