# What is the reason for using ^ in a hashcode method?

Tags: java, hashcode, xor

I found this piece of code today:

```
private static class Node{
    private final int code1;
    private final int code2;

    public Node(int code1, int code2) {
        this.code1 = code1;
        this.code2 = code2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (code1 * 31) ^ code2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Node) {
            Node node = (Node) obj;
            return node.code1 == code1 && node.code2 == code2;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a good reason for the hashcode uses **(code1 * 31) ^ code2;** ?

From my understanding, the usual way to create a hashcode is to multiply the current hashcode (or the first field) by a prime number, and add the next field, for every field.

Why would there be a need for a <strike>power</strike> XOR operator here?

Comment: This is the xor operator, rather then an exponent.

Comment: It's not a power operator. It's XOR.

Comment: Ah, indeed, mixed up the notations. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `^` is not a power, it is bit wise exclusive OR.  The purpose of a hash code is to have a random distribution and `^` has slightly better properties than `+` but not enough that most people care.

BTW There is no power operator in Java, only `Math.pow(a, b)`

---

I am probably wrong but, the way I remember it is;

You want an operation which has an equal chance of producing 0 or 1 for each bit.  This excludes multiplication, division, modulus, and, or, or shifting.  This leaves ^, -, or +.  When you overflow you lose a bit of information and `^` is the only one which doesn't overflow.

In the example above, the codes might not be larger enough to overflow, and even if you use `+` instead, I expect the difference to be very small.

---

I am not mathematical expert on the subject, but to me `+` seems a better option.  If you have the following (using 0-255 bytes, but it should be representative or what happens with `int` values)

```
int[] add = new int[256];
int[] xor = new int[256];

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
        add[(i + j) & 0xFF]++;
        xor[i ^ j]++;
    }

System.out.println("add: " + Arrays.toString(add));
System.out.println("xor: " + Arrays.toString(xor));
```

you have an equal chance of every value occurring.

```
add: [256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256]
xor: [256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256]
```

if we assume a biased distribution, such as the range of ASCII values, 0 to 127, there is a chance a bit which is not set in either value will be set with add, but not xor.

```
add: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 127, 126, 125, 124, 123, 122, 121, 120, 119, 118, 117, 116, 115, 114, 113, 112, 111, 110, 109, 108, 107, 106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 101, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
xor: [128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and you take a modulus, of say 37, the distribution appears more even with + (The difference between the most common and least common result is smaller)

add: [243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 252, 251, 250, 249, 248, 247, 246, 245, 244, 243, 242, 241, 240, 239, 238, 237, 237, 237, 237, 237, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 0, 0, ..

xor: [283, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 218, 218, 218, 218, 218, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 0, 0, ...

Comment: @Gnoupi Still it is a good question why `^` instead of `|` or `&` or `+` or `-` or `/` or `%`, basically `^` is slightly more random that `+` or `-` which are better than the others.

Comment: True. I have always seen the +, didn't really think about other ways to combine the fields.

Comment: @Gnoupi I think `+` is conceptually easier.

Comment: Probably. People tend to be wary of bitwise operators.

Comment: This [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334218/why-are-xor-often-used-in-java-hashcode-but-another-bitwise-operators-are-used?lq=1) evokes the differences with other operators. Not with +, though. But indeed, I see the point about overflowing.