# what is the ^ operator in Dart language?

Tags: dart

I have noticed the operator ^ in dart which never seen before.
Its being use in calculating the hashcode see below for details.
Here is a code snippet, check the section hashcode where i saw:

```
import './color.dart';
import './colors.dart';

class CoreState {
  final int counter;
  final Color backgroundColor;

  const CoreState({
    this.counter = 0,
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.white,
  });

  CoreState copyWith({
    int? counter,
    Color? backgroundColor,
  }) =>
      CoreState(
        counter: counter ?? this.counter,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor ?? this.backgroundColor,
      );

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
          other is CoreState &&
              runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
              counter == other.counter &&
              backgroundColor == other.backgroundColor;

  @override
  int get hashCode => counter.hashCode ^ backgroundColor.hashCode;


  @override
  String toString() {
    return "counter: $counter\n"
            "color:$backgroundColor";
  }
}
```

Comment: See the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour): It's the bitwise XOR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) explains that `^` is `bitwise XOR`. This operator is typically used for computing hash codes. For an explanation why see [Why is XOR often used in Java hascode...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334218/why-are-xor-often-used-in-java-hashcode-but-another-bitwise-operators-are-used)

Comment: THanks Patrick, this link explains well indeed.
Otherwise it didnot make sense to me using the XOR operator for hashcodes

Answer (score 2):

The ^ operator in Dart stand for XOR.

For more details, check [this](https://www.learndartprogramming.com/fundamentals/bitwise-and-shift-operators-in-dart/)

Comment: Upvote if it really helped you @SolenDogan

Comment: Benedict
I have been looking for the upvote but i could not find it, please let me know where it is

Answer (score 1):

In Dart, the `^` operator is a user-definable operator.

The traditional use of it is exclusive-or (XOR) of integers and Booleans.

```dart
var x = 170;
x = x ^ 85;
print(x); // 255;
x ^= 85;  // Same meaning as `x = x ^ 85;`.
print(x); // 170
```

and

```
var oddity = false;
for (var number in someNumbers) {
  oddity ^= element.isOdd;
}
// True if an odd number of numbers are odd.
```

You can implement the `^` operator on your own classes too. For example the [`BigInt`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/BigInt/operator_bitwise_exclusive_or.html) and [`Int32x4`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-typed_data/Int32x4/operator_bitwise_exclusive_or.html) classes do, with similar XOR-based meaning.

You could also use it for different things, say matrix exponentiation:

```dart
class Matrix {
  // ...
  Matrix operator ^(int power) {
    RangeError.checkNotNegative(power, "power");
    if (this.height != this.width) {
      throw UnsupportedError("Can only do exponents of square matrices");
    }
    var result = Matrix.identity(this.height);
    while (power > 0) { // Can be made more efficient!
      result *= this;  
      power -= 1;
    }
    return result;
  } 
}
...

  var matrix = otherMatrix ^ 2;
```

The precedence of the operator is always the same (just between `&` and `|`).

Comment: Thats a very helpful example thanks aot, never thought of operator overloading.
I will try your code snippet now
Good job my friend