# how to obfuscate an INT64?

Tags: encryption, hashmap, obfuscation

How can I obfuscate an Int64 so that it's not obvious to know the original value? I m not looking for something terrible, some a simple obfuscation method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is XOR used in cryptography?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379952/why-is-xor-used-in-cryptography)

Answer (score 1):

Xor it with a static value. Xor again with the same static value to get the original value.

Comment: with  static value you will take for the Xor ?

Comment: Just generate any random number. But remember you must use the same random number on the de-obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to obfuscate it? What are you obfuscating against?

For example, if you're trying to protect a single 64-bit integer from [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis), the xor approach will protect it somewhat. If you're looking for protection from [dynamic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis), you'll need a more complicated solution that provides anti-debugging and anti-tamper protections.

Why is this constant worth protecting? What are the programmatic constraints on this, e.g. how frequently does this value need to be revealed, just once?

Encryption with a real encryption algorithm will go further than xoring with another value and isn't actually very hard. You might use `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` (`AES` is a [current standard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), `CBC` is for chaining blocks (this doesn't matter with only 8 bytes of data), and `PKCS5Padding` is padding to allow less than the block size). There are examples all over the internet, including [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273499/6251951) (Rijndael is AES).

Comment: it's just that google api don't want we pass them a raw user id but instead that we obfuscate it. For me the user id is not a sensitive data I just need to obfucate it to be compliant with GG api

Comment: @loki Do you need the actual value, or would a hash of the value be sufficient? If so, I would look at a one-way hash like SHA256 with an appropriate salt.

Comment: unfortunately I need to get back also the value :(

Comment: Probably a more specific question about how to handle the identifier with Google APIs would get you a better answer, although I don't know that it would go on SO main site. I would expect the Google API documentation to have suggestions about how to handle this, since it seems like it would end up being a common question API users would have.