# Solidity: What does the caret ^ operator do?

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, xor

I searched solidity documentation and there's nothing on this:

What does the caret ^ operator do?

What is it doing here?

```
sha3(sha3(valueA) ^ sha3(valueB))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword I left out is "bitwise" (as Nathan mentioned).

```
So, if, for example,               sha3(valueA)=0x44=0b01000100, and
                                   sha3(valueB)=0x34=0b00110100, then:
(sha3(valueA)=0x44=0b01000100 and sha3(valueB))=0x70=0b01110000
```

PS
fun fact: XOR with all 1s is a "bit flip"

Answer (score 2):

It's a bitwise operation, XOR (exclusive or): https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/types.html

"A bitwise XOR is a binary operation that takes two bit patterns of equal length and performs the logical exclusive OR operation on each pair of corresponding bits. The result in each position is 1 if only one of the bits is 1, but will be 0 if both are 0 or both are 1." [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#:~:text=A%20bitwise%20XOR%20is%20a,0%20or%20both%20are%201](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#:%7E:text=A%20bitwise%20XOR%20is%20a,0%20or%20both%20are%201).

Answer (score 1):

Per https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_operators.htm (via Google, BTW), as in many languages, it means XOR (exclusive or):

```
x y  x^y
0 0  0
0 1  1
1 0  1
1 1  0
(1=True; 0=False)
```

Comment: Ok, what is it doing with this: sha3(sha3(valueA) ^ sha3(valueB))

Answer (score 0):

It is `xor` or `exclusive or` operator. output is true if the inputs are not alike otherwise the output is false.

```
  1 xor 1 ==  0 xor 0 = 0
  1 xor 0 ==  0 xor 1 = 1
```

[from here](https://www.101computing.net/xor-encryption-algorithm/)

> The XOR Encryption algorithm is a very effective yet easy to implement
> method of symmetric encryption. Due to its effectiveness and
> simplicity, the XOR Encryption is an extremely common component used
> in more complex encryption algorithms used nowadays.
>
> The XOR encryption algorithm is an example of symmetric encryption
> where the same key is used to both encrypt and decrypt a message.

Also [Why is XOR used in cryptography?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379952/why-is-xor-used-in-cryptography)